# Is there any embedding theorem for fibre bundles?

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, differential-topology

I would like to know whether there is an embedding theorem for fibre bundles, like Whitney embedding theorem. When can a given fibre bundle be a subbundle of some higher dimensional bundle?

Comment: There are a few comments on the subbundle of a principal fibre bundle in Kobayahi & Nomizu "Foundations of Differential Geometry, Volume 1" page 53 .

Comment: I am not looking for subbundles of bundle. I would like to know when a bundle can be embedded into another one.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, there are analogues of Whitney's embedding theorem for vector bundles.
For example:  if $X$ is a compact topological space, any real vector bundle on $X$ is a direct summand (and thus *a fortiori* a sub-bundle) of a trivial vector bundle $X\times \mathbb R^N$.
This was proved by Swan in 1962 in [this article](http://alpha.math.uga.edu/%7Epete/Swan62.pdf), Lemma 5, page 268.

There are many similar results obtained by relaxing the condition that $X$ be compact or by passing from the topological category to the $C^k$ or holomorphic or algebraic or...categories.
Actually the first theorem of this sort was proved by Serre for algebraic vector bundles on affine varieties in his immortal article [*Faisceaux Algébriques Cohérents*](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CCoQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.college-de-france.fr%2Fmedia%2Fjean-pierre-serre%2FUPL5435398796951750634_Serre_FAC.pdf&ei=AAhgU-jKNKa10wXNgYG4DA&usg=AFQjCNGrtKxDZ05Nx46IdsFrCdTAVT6bDQ&sig2=BR-MgMstBuo4cSWiPvaJ0A), always affectionately nicknamed  **FAC** .

**Edit**
As an answer to some comments below, let me add the following:
If $X$ is paracompact of finite covering dimension $d$ (for example a manifold of dimension $d$) then every vector bundle of constant rank $r$ is indeed a summand of a trivial bundle of finite rank $N$.
This is stated in Milnor-Stasheff, page 71.
I guess  that one can't bound  the rank $N$ by a function of  $r$ and $d$ alone :  $N$ might be arbitrarily large for very twisted  bundles.

Comment: In the non-compact case one manages to do it with a finite $N$?

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. To be precise, I am looking for an embedding of the second order non-holonomic frame bundle of a differential manifold into the frame bundle of some higher dimensional manifold. Is there any theorem related to this? Or, how can I apply this result? Please cite some references if you know.

Comment: @Mariano: I have added an Edit addressing your question. As a reference for Ayan, [Milnor-Stasheff](http://press.princeton.edu/titles/1571.html) is probably still unbeatable. And a PDF of that book is very easy to obtain on  line...

Comment: @GeorgesElencwajg Thank you so much.

Comment: Dear Ayan, it is my pleasure.